# How to compile RarCrack on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, gcc, clang, ld

I'm trying to compile Rarcrack by my command line, using command:

```
gcc -pthread rarcrack.c `xml2-config --libs --cflags` -O2 -o rarcrack
```

I am using the latest version of Xcode with command line tools.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_savestatus", referenced from:
      _loadstatus in rarcrack-sh2Aob.o
      _status_thread in rarcrack-sh2Aob.o
      _crack_thread in rarcrack-sh2Aob.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I keep getting these architecture errors.  Any dice on the meaning?

Comment: The instructions mention that you do "make" to build it. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: this is the first and default task in the makefile.  so this is the exact command thats run.

Comment: It's weird that you're compiling with GCC but the error is from clang. Are you on Linux or Mac?

Comment: im on mac.  and rarcrack supports mac.

Comment: @AlexV, I'm on a Mac and I had to edit the code and compile it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Today I wanted a small `.rar`/`.zip` password cracker and came across Rarcrack.

I was able to compile Rarcrack(from http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/) to Mac OSX(my Github: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/Rarcrack).

Basically, Mac OSX's version of GCC did not like the usage of the many inline functions that were in the original code. I removed the inline functions, making them normal functions and with a few other minor changes got it to compile. I checked that it worked by running rarcrack on the examples provided.

How to compile:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jaredsburrows/Rarcrack
$ cd Rarcrack
$ make
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't compile but generates 2 warnings: `rarcrack.c:274:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
rarcrack.c:315:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. I don't get why the warning shows up, since both method use `void` as a return type. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @KayJ TravisCI says my build is passing.

Comment: @Gurol'Ca The link to the source is in the my answer.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I am getting the following error
```
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```